# PHP classes why use public keyword?

Tags: php, class, public

Why should I declare class properties (variables) or methods (functions) using the keyword `public`, if they're public by default?  Or, are they?

To phrase my question differently, is `public` redundant? I understand `private` and `protected`, but why declare `public` if class members are public anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `public` is the default (see [visibility docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)).

People add it, so it is consistent with all the other methods / properties.

Furthermore, if you want to declare a property public and don't want to use `public` you will need to use `var`, which is not recommended and will likely be deprecated at some point.

Comment: For properties, ok. But who really needs public properties nowadays? For public methods, it is a matter of convention (e.g. PSR-2), which is good for familiarity and interoperability. But there is no technical benefit. And, I would argue, it does not improve readability, if your brain is not already used to seeing the public keyword.

Answer (score 3):

As of php 5.3 (I think, its been a while), using the var keyword raises E_STRICT errors, so public has to be used to declare object vaiables. As for functions, I believe it is more of a consistency thing.

Comment: Nope, it raised E_STRICT between 5.0 and 5.13 (according to doc). But they dropped the notice.

Comment: Oh really? Thanks for the heads up. I never realised it was changed back

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is redundant since that is the default visibility level. You should avoid them when you can. Some people add the `public` keyword explicitly so that code is little more readable.

Comment: @Steve: I mean you can ignore typing `public` keyword for public level vars :)

Comment: @Everyone - O ok.  I was thinking public members, which didn't make sense.  :P

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical reason to use `public` however a visibility keyword is required by PSR-2  on all functions so if you want to follow PSR-2 then you should use it:

> 4.3. Methods
>
> Visibility MUST be declared on all methods.

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#43-methods